# Error on databinding inherited control in ironpython

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ironpython

I have a class in python which inherits TextBox

```
#all imports
class IPTextBox(TextBox):
  pass
```

later I'm trying to use databinding on an object of this class

```
foo = Foo() # foo has property Text

tb = MyTextBox()
tb.DataBindings.Add('Text', foo, 'Text')
```

The last line throws an error:

**Value error: Illegal characters in path.**

When I databind to the original TextBox it works but not when I use that inherited control.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with this code?

edit:
Same thing happens using IronRuby